# Following coding problem SIGSEGV Runtime Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, runtime

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;

    do{
        vector<int> ans;
        int N=0;
        cin>>N;
        vector<int> attackArray(N), defArray(N);

        for (int i =0; i<N; i++) {
            cin>>attackArray[i];
        }
        for (int i =0; i<N; i++) {
            cin>>defArray[i];
        }


        for (int i =0; i<N; i++) {
   int nexti, previ;
if (i == 0)
{
    nexti = 1;
    previ = N - 1;
}
else if (i == N - 1)
{
    nexti = 0;
    previ = N - 2;
}
else
{
    nexti = i + 1;
    previ = i - 1;
}
if (defArray[i] > attackArray[nexti] && 
    defArray[i] > attackArray[previ] && 
    defArray[i] > attackArray[nexti] + attackArray[previ]){

        ans.push_back(defArray[i]);

    }
else {ans.push_back(-1); break;}

}

        sort(ans.begin(), ans.end(), greater<int>());
        cout<<ans[0]<<endl;

        T--;
    }while (T !=0);


    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.
The second line contains N space-separated integers a1,a2,…,aN.
The third line contains N space-separated integers d1,d2,…,dN.

**Output**

For each test case, print a single line containing one integer ― the best defense value of the shield the king gets, or −1 if Chef can be thrown in the snake pit.

**Example**

```
2

4

1 1 4 1

3 4 2 1

7

5 4 5 4 5 4 5

3 2 4 7 2 5 9
```

**Example Output**

```
3

-1
```

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. It breaks the question. And the answer.

Comment: Okay but current question's logic is still the same, but I'm still receiving the same error as before when I submit the answer. I'm not receiving with custom input as the example.

Comment: Replace all array usage with either `std::vector` or `std::array`.  Do **not** use "regular" arrays at all, and for goodness sakes, get rid of the variable-length-array nonsense you're using now.  Then ensure that you're not going out-of-bounds when using std::vector/std::array by replacing `[ ]` with the call to `at()`.  If you are going out of bounds, instead of SIGSEGV you would get a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown.  For example `attackArray.at(nextI)` instead of `attackArray[nextI]`.

Comment: If you remove entirely regular / VLA usage, stick with using vector or std::array, and then use `at()`, you will more than likely discover that the issue is an out-of-bounds access error.  The goal is to totally eliminate undefined behavior, and a good start is to again, drop usage of regular arrays, stay with std::vector / std::array, and take advantage of the self-debugging features such as usage of the `at()` call.  More than likely you will discover that your original code you say works for some test cases was actually faulty all along.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your sequence of `if` statements should be one `if ... else if ... else` statement.

```
if (i == 0)
    ...
else if (i==N-1)
    ...
else
    ...
```

Just because a previous `if` condiition has evaluated to true doesn't stop code after the `if` statement from executing unless you use an `else`. So the condition in your third `if` statement is executing even when `i == 0` or `i == N - 1`, resulting in an out of bounds array access and a crash.

Also

```
int attackArray[N],defArray[N];
```

is not legal C++ because all array sizes must be compile time constants. You are clearly using a compiler which doesn't care, but you should, so use this instead

```
vector<int> attackArray(N), defArray(N);
```

Finally there's a lot of duplicated code in your different conditions. You could simplify a lot by adding a couple of extra variables for the next and previous values of `i`. E.g.

```
int nexti, previ;
if (i == 0)
{
    nexti = 1;
    previ = N - 1;
}
else if (i == N - 1)
{
    nexti = 0;
    previ = N - 2;
}
else
{
    nexti = i + 1;
    previ = i - 1;
}
if (defArray[i] > attackArray[nexti] && 
    defArray[i] > attackArray[previ] && 
    defArray[i] > attackArray[nexti] + attackArray[previ])
    ...
```

Comment: Okay I'll try to implement.

Comment: Runtime error : SIGSEGV while example given works,I get the error when I submit the answer.